# Google Cloud Platform: How to run Ruby on Rails delayed_jobs automatically ( not using command line ) in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, delayed-job

We have been able to successfully run delayed jobs in development mode using 
rake:jobs work

We have deployed our Rails application to google cloud platform and we are not sure How to run  delayed_jobs automatically ( not using command line ) in production

If we run localhost production server and manually run 
ruby bin/delayed_job run ( for windows) it works 
We are not sure how to achieve this automatically without using command line.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link to run delayed job automatically when server starts without running manually on console rake jobs:work

[Start or ensure that Delayed Job runs when an application/server restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580871/start-or-ensure-that-delayed-job-runs-when-an-application-server-restarts)

Note: deamons gem dosen't work for windows but the same will run on linux or mac

OR

copy the code into your `initializers/delayed_job_config.rb`

```rb
DELAYED_JOB_PID_PATH = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pids/delayed_job.pid"

def start_delayed_job
  Thread.new do
    `ruby bin/delayed_job start`
  end
end

def daemon_is_running?
  pid = File.read(DELAYED_JOB_PID_PATH).strip
  Process.kill(0, pid.to_i)
  true
rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH   # file or process not found
  false
end

start_delayed_job unless daemon_is_running?
```